# Issues with installing GDAL for Python 3.7.3

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

I am having trouble trying to install GDAL in python 3.7.3.
Does anyone out there have any experience installing this? Also, this is the first time I'm asking here. Please do assist or kindly direct me to anyone who can offer advice on this?
Thanks in advance.

```
pip install GDAL
    Collecting GDAL
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/09/cac5021db34f5c95c6a660b90e5d27062a520fe32a0493f68d07a7055d30/GDAL-3.0.4.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: GDAL
      Building wheel for GDAL (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\Farhan\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Farhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bwqvn3wb\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Farhan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-0gdpm9_l' --python-tag cp37:
      ERROR: running bdist_wheel

        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\Farhan\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Farhan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bwqvn3wb\\GDAL\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Farhan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yg5kb88q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Farhan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bwqvn3wb\GDAL\
```

Comment: GDAL isn't distributed in binary form, so your machine needs to compile it. Like the error message says, you're missing a compiler: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: Since you're using Anaconda, I would try to avoid `pip install`. Most binaries are available via conda, try `conda install gdal -c conda-forge` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chris Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) has a fantastic repository of pre-built python wheels for windows, amongst them `GDAL`.

So depending on the `GDAL` version desired, the python version used and your system (`win_amd64`?) you can just download the corresponding wheel file and install it locally using `pip`.

---

E.g. to install `GDAL 3.0.4`, running under `python3.7` on a 64bit machine, you need to download:

`GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

and install it

`pip3 install C:\Users\foo\bar\GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Sidenote:

For installing modules, especially complex like gdal, it always pays off to use a virtual environment, as provided by e.g. `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm able to get it running smoothly for now.

Comment: @Handodol Great, if it answered your question please accept the answer as solution.

Comment: ERROR: GDAL-3.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Same with win32. Windows 7/64 (pip 20.2.1)

Comment: Unfortunately this specific combination of GDAL version and Python version is not available as wheel. OSgeo4W apparently installs version 3.0.4 by default (haven't found yet how to update).

Answer (score 0):

Addding to the answer by Val, you can also try installing it with conda.

1. Install Anaconda or Miniconda.
2. Create a new enviroment with the Python version you need:
   `conda create --name MyEnviroment python=3.7.3`
3. Enter/Activate the enviroment and install your Python packages (First the ones you need from conda like gdal, after that the ones you need from pip:
   `conda activate MyEnviroment`
   `conda install gdal`
   `pip install ...`
   Note: You know you are inside an enviroment after you activated it because it displays the name of it before your current directory, for example: `(MyEnviroment) PS D:\MY\DIRECTORY\SCRIPTS>`
4. Run your scripts while your conda enviroment is active:
   `(MyEnviroment) PS D:\MY\DIRECTORY\SCRIPTS> python MyScript.py`
5. After you finish you can close the terminal or deactivate your enviroment with:
   `conda deactivate`

Installing conda packages usually gives less problems than installing packages from pip, because of the way the packages are made.

Answer (score 0):

how I handled this problem was by using https://colab.research.google.com/. With that I just`pip install gdal or !pip install gdal`